# How to rename a node in jtree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I create a Jtree that all of its nodes have User object, I fill user object by ItemInfo class, now my problem is with renaming a node. I can edit my node but since I try to find my UserObject I saw when I press F2 and rename my node, new name place in my UserObject!

So now I want to know I should touch where to replace new name of my node with previous name manually?

I guess I need to write my own DefaultTreeCellRenderer class, please advice me... (if yes any example for my reference)

```
public class ItemInfo {
    public String Name;
    public String Value;
    public long ValueID;


    public ItemInfo(String Name, String Value) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    public ItemInfo(String Name, long ValueID) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.ValueID = ValueID;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return Value;
    }

    public long getValueID() {
        return ValueID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you add `TreeModelListener` as described in [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#dynamic) tutorial? In the listener you can be notified if a node was changed and update its user object.

**EDIT:** See DefaultTreeModel.valueForPathChanged javadoc:

> This sets the user object of the
>   TreeNode identified by path and posts
>   a node changed. If you use custom user
>   objects in the TreeModel you're going
>   to need to subclass this and set the
>   user object of the changed node to
>   something meaningful.

Override this method and update your object with new node name.

Comment: Yes you right I implement treeNodesChanged, but problem is when I check my node it's already replaced with new object. I mean before on that node UseroBject fill by my object, but now it's replace by just a string(new name of node)!I want to know where this changes will happen? or How I can have my previous node

Comment: but would you tell me how u find this solution? by googling? previous experience?

Comment: @rima: I haven't used editable trees before, I was going through swing source code to find where the change occurs and found that method. IDE helped a lot in this case (I'm using IntelliJ IDEA).