# How to rename a custom JTree node

Tags: java, swing, rename, jtree

I have a JTree that contains custom nodes that look something like this:

```
Root
  + [TypeA]: Name1
  + [TypeB]: Name2
  - [TypeC]: Name3
    + [TypeD]: Name4
```

When I select a node and choose to rename it, I want the user to only be able to rename the "name", and not the "type".  So for example, if the second child is selected and a rename operation is started, I want the Node to change to an edit field but I only want "Name2" to be visible for editing.  Once the name change is done, I want to repopulate the tree with "[TypeB]: NewName"

I have the rename operation working right now, but I don't know how to force the rename to only show the "name" and not the "type" while renaming is happening.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685068/how-to-rename-a-node-in-jtree ?